# Text Along slider on wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress site I'm designing for a friends school. If you look at the home page:

http://freelanceaccounting.co.za

There is a slider there. Now i want to insert some text next to it But it doesn't work it either puts it above or below it.

is there a plugin I'm supposed to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you are using the education hub theme and huge slider which is not default by  the theme.
May be theme contains the option to add text on their default slider. Please check that. if you want to use that plugin of huge slider then you can also check for that option. if it has not any option then you need customization either by theme or plugin.